# What is wrong with my 16 bit adder? How can I fix it?

Tags: adder

I did this 16 bit adder in a simulator.  Something is wrong. The automatic check returned FAIL.  What did I do wrong? How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Please draw a neat version of this circuit. It is not clear which lines are connected or just in the background, which makes spotting the mistake nearly impossible.

Comment: At the very least, if your buses are numbered starting from the bottom, arrange your adders in the same order!

Answer (score 2):

You maximised lines crossing in the drawing.
This makes it difficult to spot missing connections, such as the carry from bit 1 to bit 2 (starting bit numbering at 0).

It may be easier to design a 4-bit full adder -
and the 16-bit adder from 4-bit adders.